# An apparent contradiction in SU(3) structure constants?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

According to http://www.phys.washington.edu/users/ellis/Phys5578/SU3_5.htm or the related [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_constants), the following equation should hold:

$[ \frac{\lambda_3}{2}, \frac{\lambda_4}{2}]  = i f^{345}  \frac{\lambda_5}{2}  $

and indeed one can check that $ \frac{\lambda_3}{2} \frac{\lambda_4}{2} - \frac{\lambda_4}{2} \frac{\lambda_3}{2} = i \frac{1}{2} \frac{\lambda_5}{2}$.

However, upon permutation of indices, the equation
$[ \frac{\lambda_4}{2}, \frac{\lambda_5}{2}]  = i f^{453}  \frac{\lambda_3}{2}  $
no longer holds (where I'm assuming $f^{453} = \frac{1}{2}$).

Rather, using the standard Gell-Mann matrices, I get that
$[ \frac{\lambda_4}{2}, \frac{\lambda_5}{2}]  - i f^{453}  \frac{\lambda_3}{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 
i/4 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & i/4 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & -i/2  
\end{pmatrix} $

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't permute the indices like you would in SU(2). Looking at the table you have for the structure constant you should notice that the only $f^{ijk}$ which has a $4$ and a $5$ is $f^{458}$. This means that the commutator of $0.5 \lambda_4$ and $0.5 \lambda_5$ will be proportional to $\lambda_8$ not $\lambda_3$.

Comment: ah, interesting. do you know of any reading that covers this particular point? and how come it works for $f^{534}$?

Comment: Chapter 2 in Robert Cahn's "Semi-simple Lie Algebras and Their Representations" (http://phyweb.lbl.gov/~rncahn/www/liealgebras/texall.pdf) includes an accessible discussion of su(3).